# One delegate class for multiple NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have several `NSFetchedResultsControllers` throughout my app, and in every view controller, I implement the respective delegate methods. However, instead of copying these delegate methods into every class that implements an `NSFetchedResultsController`, I thought I would just create a class that implements these delegate methods, and set all fetched results controller's delegate to point to that one class. Here's what I've tried, which doesn't work:

Since the delegate methods need to know which table view they are making changes to, I thought I would just create a separate delegate class for each fetched results controller, and send a pointer to the tableview for that class:

```
FetchedResultsDelegate *delegate = [[FetchedResultsDelegate alloc] initWithTableView:parentTableView];
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate=delegate;
[delegate release];
```

However, this causes a `BAD_ACCESS` crash, so this means that I probably shouldn't be doing what I'm doing above.

How can I create a single delegate class that handles all delegate requests for all my `NSFetchedResultsControllers`?

**Edit:** I was able to fix the problem by doing `@property (nonatomic, retain) FetchedResultsDelegate *delegate;` Is this ok? Some people are saying something about assign rather than retain?

Comment: what iOS are you using? Do you use ARC?

Comment: are both delegate is holding "assign" attribute ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: when you define @property for the delegates did you retain it or assign it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is retaining your `FetchedResultsDelegate` as delegate properties are normally declared as assign. e.g. [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) declares the delegate as

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> delegate
```

Therefore you created the object and destroyed it straight away, but gave the fetchedResultsController a nasty dangling pointer.

To fix this you need a retain on the delegate. So in your UITableViewController class add a new property

```
// .h
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> tableViewDelegate;

// .m
@synthesize tableViewDelegate = _tableViewDelegate;
```

then when you hook up you delegate just change your code to this

```
FetchedResultsDelegate *delegate = [[FetchedResultsDelegate alloc] initWithTableView:parentTableView];
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = delegate;
self.tableViewDelegate = delegate;
[delegate release]; delegate = nil;
```

### Don't forget

Release this new ivar in the dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc;
{
    // ... other releases
    [_tableViewDelegate release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

---

The use of assign is all about ownership semantics.

In this case your `UITableViewController` should own the tableView's delegate (e.g. `strong`/`retain`) as nothing else is.

The reason that the `NSFetchedResultsController` uses `assign` and not `retain`/`strong` is because there is a good chance that the object that created it would act as the delegate, which would result in both objects owning each other (both having a `retain` held on each other), which causes a retain cycle

Comment: What if I do `@property (nonatomic, retain) FetchedResultsDelegate *delegate;`?